# Choices and satisfaction

Tags: decision-making

Say person A can choose from some items one to be his own. After some time he can come back and replace it with another.

A person B can choose as well but cannot replace once chosen.

Are both the persons going to be satisfied/ dissatisfied after their first choice? Has any study been done related to this?